# FBSDKGameRequestDialog with FBSDKGameRequestFilterAppNonUsers error

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to implement game invitations (ie. inviting friends who are not users of the app to try the app) on an iOS app (which already has a working Facebook login system). There seems to be several possible ways of doing this, each with their own different requirements. FBSDKGameRequestDialog seems like a promising way of doing this. The tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests says:

"Alternatively, by specifying app_non_users, the sender will only see friends who have previously not authenticated the app. This should be used when using requests for inviting new users to the game."

This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I therefore tried this:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent* content = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent new] autorelease];
content.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeSend;
content.filters = FBSDKGameRequestFilterAppNonUsers;
content.message = @"something";
content.title = @"something";
content.objectID = @"1"; // No idea what to put here

FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog new] autorelease];
dialog.content = content;
dialog.delegate = self;

NSError* error = nil;
if(![dialog validateWithError: &error])
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
else
    [dialog show];
```

The dialog launches, but calls the delegate with an error, namely:

Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=100 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid fbid.}

That error message is not very helpful, nor can I find anywhere why it's happening, or what the exact requirements are for this to be possible. (Yes, I am logged successfully into Facebook. Everything else is working just fine. I have no idea where that "Invalid fbid" is coming from.)

The same tutorial page offers an alternative to do this, by requesting a list of invitable friends explicitly, and using your own GUI. However, it says:

"This feature is only available to games with a presence on Facebook Desktop"

Obviously it doesn't bother telling what that means, or give a link to further information. And of course making the request doesn't work. (The error says "please set a Canvas URL in your app's settings", which I have no idea what it means or how to do it, even after browsing Facebook's own documentation and googling.)

Either way, I would prefer the SDK's own dialog for this, as it's much less work.

Answer (score 0):

`objectId` refers to the "Open Graph object ID of the object being sent.". Lets say I am sending you 100 Coins of your in-app currency, then this would be the ID of the object you created for that "gift".

You don't have to provide a value for it if you are not planning to send around in-game items, and in your example, 1 is obviously not a valid ID for an object. The message could be more descriptive though.